# How to enter data in specific manner in excel using java poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is my code so what i need to change as I need 2 arraylists to be stored in a way that is displayed in below image. The code I have written stores data in diagonal form.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String element = null;
        int numberOfInput = 0, numberOfStates = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> states = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //for creating excel sheet
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(element);

        int rowCount = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<states.size();i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            //int columnCount = 0;
            row.createCell(i).setCellValue(states.get(i));             
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(element+".xlsx");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: Need this as output]

Comment: I guess you'll be needing two for loops

Comment: Is number of states getting printed diagonally?

Comment: Yes its is printed diagonally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column number is going to be constant for number of state, there is no need the keep it variable.

```
for (int i=0;i<states.size();i++) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
        //int columnCount = 0;
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(states.get(i));             
    }
```